# ROS CV_Bridge linking: undefined reference to cv_bridge::toCvShare(...)

Tags: opencv, boost, linker, ros

I recently set up a new computer with ROS and OpenCV. But in the first test project I can't get ROS **cv_bridge to link correctly**.

The error after rosmake is:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/motion_detector.dir/src/motion_detector.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable bin/motion_detector
CMakeFiles/motion_detector.dir/src/motion_detector.cpp.o: In function `imageCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
/home/sh/workspace/ros/motion_detection_01/src/motion_detector.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cv_bridge::toCvShare(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, std::string const&)'
```

But cv_bridge is there. Running roscd cv_bridge shows my the folder and all. 
Google didn't really show my anything to "*undefined references to cv_bridge::..*". What maked me suspicious is that the error says 'undefined reference to cv_bridge::toCvShare(**boost::shared_ptr**

**Can you help me to fix this? Thx!**

Here are my project files:

*motion_detection.cpp*

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  try
  {
    //cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8)->image);
    cv::Mat _img = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg , "bgr8")->image;
...
```

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/include/opencv)
include_directories(/usr/local/include/opencv2)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage

...

set(ROS_LINK_FLAGS "-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d")

...

rosbuild_add_executable(motion_detector src/motion_detector.cpp)
target_link_libraries(motion_detector opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_nonfree)
```

*manifest.xml*

```
<package>
  <description brief="motion_detection_01">

     motion_detection_01

  </description>
  <author>basti</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/motion_detection_01</url>

  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depent package="cv_bridge"/> 
  <depend package="genmsg"/>
  <depend package="sensor_msgs"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="image_transport"/>

</package>
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo. Take a close look at the line `<depent package="cv_bridge"/>` in `manifest.xml` (should be `depend`, not `depent`). Perhaps this causes the problem?

Comment: so ashamed. THANK YOU, that was it.